# laravel controller responsible for error 500

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have been trying to complete an ajax request. However the form submission is giving me error 500. I created a controller to process the form submission. at first i thought the problem was due to _token. But i added token and problem was not fixed. Then i changed my post route and processed the request on the route page and this seems to work. I still want to use a controller to process the form submission.

### Routes

```
    //this does not
    Route::post('/mail',[ 
    'uses'=>'ContactController@postContact',
    'as'=>'postContact'
    ]);
    //this works
    Route::post('/mail2',function(){
    return response()->json([
        'result'=>'success'
    ]);
  });
```

### Problem controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\ContactModel;
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function getContactList()
    {
        $contacts = Contact::all();
        return response()->json([
            'contacts'=>$contacts
        ]);
    }
    public function postContact(Requests $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'result'=>'success'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Any idea whats going on?

## Fixed: It was a typo guys.

```
        public function postContact(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'result'=>'success'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Turn error reporting on and check what the error is. My guess is `Requests` is a typo.

Comment: Are you calling right controller `PostController` ? and not `ContactController`

Comment: @apokryfos you are right.